# Let $p$ be a nonzero prime element of an integral domain D. Show that $p$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a nonzero prime element of an integral domain D. This means
that whenever $p$ divides a product $ab$ with $a, b \in D$, it must divide $a$ or $b$. Show that $p$ is irreducible.

I tried to solve this question by assuming p is reducible, then there exists $a,b \in D$ such that $ab = p$.

$\Rightarrow p\vert ab$

Since p is a prime element

$\Rightarrow p\vert a$ or $p\vert b$

Assume $p\vert a $ WLOG
then $a= pc $ for some $c \in D$

$\therefore p=ab =pcb$

$\Rightarrow p(1-cb) = 0 $

$\Rightarrow p = 0 $ or $bc =1$

Since p is nonzero, so bc=1. Then b and c are units.

After this I don't know how to prove it. 
Could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: You began your proof with $p=ab$. What does it mean if $b$ is a unit? :)

Comment: It's proved: the only possible decomposition of $p$ as a product of two elements is trivial (one of the factors must be a unit).

Comment: To me, a prime element is by definition an irreducible element...

Comment: @Surb Consider 3 in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. 3 is prime in this ring, yet $3 = 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times \ldots$ Of course $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is *not* an integral domain. I don't remember where I got this example from.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof started out much like the proof of Theorem 1.21 in Alaca & Williams *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory*, but then you overcomplicated things with $a = pc$.

> Let $p \in D$ be a prime and suppose that $p = ab$, where $a, b \in D$. As $ab = p \cdot 1$, we have $p \mid ab$, and so, as $p$ is prime, we deduce $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$ ... Since $1 = a / p \cdot b$ or $1 = a / b \cdot p$, either $b$ is a unit or $a$ is a unit of $D$.